# SQL parent/child hierarchy

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table as shown below which has a parent/child relation.

[image: source data]

My output should look like this:

[image]

Comment: You might want to provide some additional info plus your current attempt.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Let us see your work and maybe we can guide you better - did you try joining the tables?

Comment: Do a self left join.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `join`:

```
select pc.*, pcp.id as parentid
from parentchild pc left join
     parentchild pcp
     on pc.childbook = pcp.parentbook;
```

I don't think I quite understand why the parent of "1" is "1.1" and why `parentId` is associated with **child**book, but that appears to be what you are asking for.

Comment: That helps, pardon the names there. i was joining the wrong child and parent earlier.

Comment: one more query, how do i get the book which don't have a child in a separate flag?

Comment: @Abrah . . . That is what the `left join` does.